# What is meant by (Sky Walker)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

**1-** Is the term **(sky walker)** connected to taking selfies at high structures (like skyscrapers) specifically or at any dangerous place in general (like cliffs, etc.)
***In other words:*** Is the term **(sky walker)** connected to (height) or to (bravery) or even to (recklessness)?

**2-** What does the author mean by the last sentence:

This kind of art ***seems to have been lost somewhere*** between the ground and the sky?

Thank you.

Comment: I have found those two different meanings of (Sky Walkers):
1- One who works or worked in high steel in New York City.
(by extension from previous) Any high ironworker.
One who walks along a skywalk, or skyway, or people who climb tall structures for thrills or photography.
[yourdictionary.com]
2- someone that is brave but can be afraid at times but they never lose hope in what they believe in. Skywalkers are courageous, strong, handsome/beautiful, awesome, amazing, loving etc.
example:
Firefighter saves someone from a building
Woman: WOW! That man is a skywalker!
[Urban Dicitionay]

Comment: _Sky walker_ just means a person who walks in the sky, referring to the photographer climbing high structures. No doubt it was influenced by the name of the character Luke Skywalker in the 'Star Wars' films.

Comment: I have added a comment, I hope you've seen it.

Comment: Don't take Urban Dictionary's definitions too seriously.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. What about the last sentence. What does the author mean by (this kind of art seems to have been lost somewhere between the ground and the sky)?

Comment: I don't know - that's why I only answered your first question!

Comment: I have added a photo if it would help. Thank you.

Comment: We can only guess 'what the author meant'. NB The moderators of this forum won't like your posting an image instead of quoting the text.

Comment: I added the image just to make reading easier and clearer. I hope he'd take it into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text says the nickname 'sky walker' was originally *earned* by an individual through his work of climbing high structures for photographs. It seems that 'sky walker' is meant to mean '*one who walks in the sky*'. By extension, this has then become a term for people who imitate the same art.

In Native American culture, the term 'walker' is used to mean that someone *walks with* something in the sense that they *work with*, or *have dealings with* it - for examples, look up the terms 'spirit walker' or 'skin walker'. Likewise in English, 'to walk *with*' someone or something can have the meaning of being in union with, or being associated with it. So, 'sky walker' could also suggest the idea of having a relationship with the things of the sky or the sky itself. It could simply have been coined because, in the selfies, they appear to be walking in the sky. The choice of nickname and subsequent term for this art could of course also be a reference to, or have been inspired by, *Star Wars*, where 'Skywalker' is the family name of several major characters.

---

I understand the statement "*this kind of art seems to have been lost somewhere between the ground and the sky*" to mean this trend began as *art*, but that some people are doing it for other reasons. Art is meant to be seen by people, and appreciated. If someone was to take part in this activity for the danger alone, putting themselves in a dangerous position, they may not survive for their art to be appreciated.

Saying that something has "*got lost between [x] and [y]*" is a fairly common expression used both literally and figuratively. In this case, the ground and the sky are the two furthest points and I think it has just been phrased that way as a metaphor to represent two polarised reasons for doing the activity.

Comment: The title of the text is (Sky Walkers), and it mainly speaks about people (in general) who take dangerous selfies just to post them on FB or Insta or Snap. I have added a photo of the whole lesson to make it clear. Thank you.

Comment: @LaithLeo I've updated my answer to address your updated question. If you have further questions you should open a new question as the site rules are really to have one focused question.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for your answer.